# Name column is missing in power apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I am trying to edit the document library with Power Apps, and I have an issue. When I open the document library with Power Apps, I can only see the title column, not the Name column. I can add the Name column from the Add fields option; however, it won't add anything.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From my tests I can't reproduce your problem, when I customize my library in the power apps, we can add the name column and the existing filename will appear:

[image]
[image]

If your library is new and no files have been uploaded, the name column defaults to null:

[image]

Comment: Hi Julie, thanks for your message. When I create a new document set, the name column is grayed out. Please see the attachment. So what I have done is by using Power Apps to create a drop-down column as a lookup to get the information from another site collection. So the document library has only Name and Company columns, and when I want to create a new document set, I am having this issue. But if I upload a file, it will pick up the file name and work fine.

Comment: Per my test document set name will still be available in power apps form.